# Remove some text from jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, replace

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<input type='text' name='af_student_startdate' id='start115'>
<input type='text' name='af_student_startdate' id='start116'>
```

And the following `jQuery`

```
$('#save').click(function() {

    var values = {};

    $('input[name="af_student_startdate"]').each(function(n, el){
        values [ $(el).attr('id') ] = $(el).val();
    });

    $.ajax( {
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/update.php',
    data : {af_student_startdate: values}
  });

})
```

This will `POST` for example:

```
af_student_startdate[start115]  2012-09-01
af_student_startdate[start116]  2012-09-25
```

How can I remove the text "start" so that I only POST the `INT` values to update.php?

Comment: its making an index in af_student_startdate automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
values [ $(el).attr('id').match(/\d+/g) ] = $(el).val();
```

You can also code:

```
values [ this.id.match(/\d+/g) ] = this.value;
```

Which is faster and better than creating unnecessary jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do this

```
<form method="POST" action="/update.php" id="af_student_startdate_update_form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type='text' name='af_student_startdate[115]' id='start115'>
<input type='text' name='af_student_startdate[116]' id='start116'>
</form>

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/update.php',
    data : $('#af_student_startdate_update_form').serialize();
})
```